I am having issues with setting the httpOnly cookie for the refresh token in expressjs and getting that cookie back when I want to get a new accessTo
I am building MERN stack app when the user login the user will be issued an access token and refresh token the refresh token will stored in an httpOnly cookie when the access token expires the refresh token controller in the backend should send an ew access token but this controller cannot find the refresh token from the req.cookies or the req.headers.cookie.
When the user login in the dev tools network tab I can see the refresh token set correctly in the cookies. My frontend run on '' http://localhost:3000" and my backend run on "http://localhost:3500" I have also added credential: "include" when requesting the new access token. I test that with thunder client and it works but it doesn't work with the frontend code (other integrations that doesn't require JWT works properly).
Is that because the client browser didn't send the refresh token cookie? and how I solve this issue. This is the code which set the refresh token cookie when the user login
res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: false, path: '/' , maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 120});

and this is the refresh token controller
const handleRefreshToken = async (req, res) => {
const cookie = req.headers.cookie;
const refreshToken = cookie && cookie.split('jwt=')[1];

clojure
Copy
if (!refreshToken) return res.sendStatus(401);

const foundUser = await User.findOne({ refreshToken }).exec();
if (!foundUser) return res.sendStatus(403); // Forbidden

jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err || foundUser.email !== decoded.email) return res.sendStatus(403);
    
    const roles = Object.values(foundUser.roles);
    const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        {
            "UserInfo": {
                "email": decoded.email,
                "roles": roles
            }
        },
        process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: '10s' }
    );

    res.json({ roles, accessToken });
});
}

and its endpoint is this '' http://localhost:3500/refresh" when I request a new access token I get 401 error from the refresh token controller. In the frontend I am using RTK Query, and this is the code which will check the access token and issue a new access token if the previous has expired
 export const activityApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'activities',
  tagTypes: ['activities', 'groupActivities'],
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ 
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3500',
    prepareHeaders: async (headers) => {
      const accessToken = Cookies.get("accessToken");
      
      if (!accessToken) {
        return headers;
      }

      headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);

      const decodedToken = decodeAccessToken(accessToken);
      if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 > Date.now()) {
        return headers;
      }

      try {
        const refreshedToken = await refreshAccessToken();
        headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${refreshedToken}`);
        Cookies.set('accessToken', refreshedToken);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to refresh token:', error);
      }
      
      return headers;
    }
  }),

and this is the required functions
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export function decodeAccessToken(accessToken:string) {
  try {
    const tokenParts = accessToken.split('.');
    if (tokenParts.length !== 3) {
      throw new Error('Invalid token');
    }
    const payload = JSON.parse(atob(tokenParts[1]));
    return payload;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error decoding access token:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

export async function refreshAccessToken() {
  try {
    
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3500/refresh', {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include', 
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      
      throw new Error('Failed to refresh token');
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    const { accessToken } = data;
    Cookies.set('accessToken', accessToken); // Update the access token in cookies
    return accessToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error refreshing token:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

If there is any solution that I can use with refresh and access token instead of this that will be a great help.
If any body can solve this problem I will really appreciate that
Thanks
I have tried to test that with thunder client and everything is working properly but when I integrate that with my frontend code the problems arise and I get 401 error in the console of the browser.
When I login I can see in the network tab the jwt cookie in the Response Cookies
As I said no problems with cors because I test that with thunder client and I am also using the cookie-parser in the backend and js-cookie in the frontend
